# Google Sheets Split Formula Keep Leading Zeroes

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am trying to split this number that is in one cell of its own in I2: 0000320193-20-000096
However, when I use the formula '=split(I2, "-")', it gives me three cells with the following: "320193" , "20" , "96".

I need the zeroes behind each number to stay with each number, I just need the hyphens to be removed and each separate number to be in their own cells.

I have tried '=split(I2, "'-")'; however, this does not work either.

In addition, all the cells are formatted to be "plain text."

I can make it work if I use the "split by column" tool; however, it's tedious and removes the surrounding text to I2, which I need.

How can I change this formula to keep the zeroes in front of each number?

Thanks!

Comment: are the three numbers always 11 digits, 2 digits and 6 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT("'"&I2&"'", "-"), "'", ""))
```

This will append apostrophe in the beginning and end of cell `I2` to avoid auto formatting and since `SPLIT` return an array, we need `ARRAYFORMULA` to apply the `SUBSTITUTE` to all array element.

Output:

[image]

### References:

- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "'-'")&"'", "-"), "(.*)'"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

`=regexextract(I2, "(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)")`